# Flutter Circular Countdown Timer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am trying to create a timer app which has multiple countdown timer for different task. The issue, I am facing is that, if I start a one-timer, and press the back button, the timer stops. So I want, that timer to run till either it is being paused or the timer ends and alerts the user, or the app is destroyed. Help me how can I do this using Flutter? Any Sample Code Will be Appreciated?
Please Help Me out, guys.
I have been stuck with this problem for a month. Don't know how to pass away from it guys.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
  import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
 import 'package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart';
   import 'package:flash_chat/components/button.dart';
  import 'package:flash_chat/screens/promotersDetails.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

  class ViewPromoters extends StatefulWidget {
 final String a_id, s_id;
    ViewPromoters({Key key, @required this.a_id, @required this.s_id})
   : super(key: key);

  @override
 _ViewPromotersState createState() => _ViewPromotersState(a_id, s_id);
   }

   class _ViewPromotersState extends State<ViewPromoters> {
    CountDownController _controller = CountDownController();

  var descList = [
"Engagement Selfie = 5",
"Engagement Selfie = 7",
"Engagement Selfie = 9",
"Engagement Selfie = 7",
 "Engagement Selfie = 3",
];
 var selfieList = [
"Sampling Selfie = 5",
"Sampling Selfie = 7",
"Sampling Selfie = 9",
"Sampling Selfie = 7",
"Sampling Selfie = 3",
];
var dataList = [
"Data Collection = 5",
"Data Collection = 7",
"Data Collection = 9",
"Data Collection = 7",
"Data Collection = 3",
];
 var timeList = [
"Last Selfie Time = 04:25 PM",
"Last Selfie Time = 04:20 PM",
"Last Selfie Time = 05:10 PM",
"Last Selfie Time = 03:20 PM",
"Last Selfie Time = 04:00 PM",
 ];

// Image Name List Here
 var imgList = [
"images/img1.jpg",
"images/img2.jpg",
"images/img3.jpg",
"images/img4.jpg",
"images/img5.jpg",
 ];
String p_id, p_name;
Map mapResponse;
List listResponse;
String a_id, s_id;
_ViewPromotersState(this.a_id, this.s_id);
Future fetchdata() async {
print(s_id); // Supervisor Id
var url = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    "http://demo.likemyfiles.com/DS/api/api_supervisor/supervisor/$s_id"));
setState(() {
  mapResponse = json.decode(url.body);
  print(mapResponse);
  listResponse = mapResponse['promoters'];
  print(listResponse);
});
}

@override
void initState() {
fetchdata();
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // App Bar
    title: Text(
      "Promoters Detail",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.notifications_active,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Notify();
        },
      )
    ],
    elevation: 5,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  // Main List View With Builder
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 3,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          p_id = listResponse[index]['id'].toString();
          print(p_id);
          p_name = listResponse[index]['name'].toString();
          showDialogFunc(context, imgList[index], p_name, descList[index],
              timeList[index], p_id, a_id);
        },
        // Card Which Holds Layout Of ListView Item
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 5,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              **CircularCountDownTimer(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                duration: 120,
                fillColor: Colors.green,
                ringColor: Colors.white,
                controller: _controller,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
                strokeWidth: 10.0,
                strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
                isTimerTextShown: true,
                isReverse: false,
                onComplete: () {
                  Notify();
                },
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
              ),**
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 60,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage(imgList[index]),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: listResponse == null
                              ? Container()
                              : Text(
                                  listResponse[index]['name'].toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: width,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.add_task_sharp,
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                size: 20.0,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 7,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                descList[index],
                                maxLines: 3,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: width,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.add_photo_alternate_outlined,
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                size: 20.0,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 7,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                selfieList[index],
                                maxLines: 3,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: width,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.dashboard_customize,
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                size: 20.0,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 7,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                dataList[index],
                                maxLines: 3,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: width,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.assignment_ind_sharp,
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                size: 20.0,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 7,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                timeList[index],
                                maxLines: 3,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
 }
 }

 // This is a block of Model Dialog
showDialogFunc(context, img, title, desc, time, promoter_id, activity_id) {
return showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (context) {
  return Center(
    child: Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        height: 400,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              child: Image.asset(
                img,
                width: 140,
                height: 140,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 2,
            ),
            Container(
              // width: 200,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  time,
                  maxLines: 3,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey[500]),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Button(
                title: 'Attendance Photos',
                colour: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () {
                  print(activity_id);
                  print(promoter_id);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PromotersDetails(
                              url:
                                  URL,
                              title: "Attendance Selfie",
                            )),
                  );
                }),
            Button(
                title: 'Engagement Photos',
                colour: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PromotersDetails(
                              url:
                                  URL,
                              title: "Engagement Selfie",
                            )),
                  );
                }),
            Button(
                title: '  Sampling Photos  ',
                colour: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PromotersDetails(
                              url:
                                  URL,  
                              title: "Sampling Photos",
                            )),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  },
);
 }

 void Notify() async {
 await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
      id: 1,
      channelKey: 'key1',
      title: 'This is Notification',
      body: 'T His is body of Notify'));
  }
```

Comment: I think because of the single-threaded nature of Dart, leaving an activity and moving to another one will stop the previous thread and continue with the new one. 
Although dart has what you call isolates, Isolates help you work with more than one thread at the same time.

Comment: Can you give give me some idea about isolates 
how i can implement isolates in this code

Comment: At the moment, I can only point you to resources.

Comment: Article 
https://dev.to/alphamikle/why-should-you-use-isolates-in-flutter-1k5o

Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF8LwonwKhg

Answer (score -1):

tbh. i know this is a bad approach and performance on device may suffer. but you can define a controller in the state of the app. and then pass that controller in your timer. this is a very bad approach and you need to handle when to dispose off it. but its a workaround if nothing is working.